# Call JS function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, mouseevent

I am new to JS.  I am using Homestead Sitebuilder to edit/create my website.

I am trying to call a JS function by triggering an HTML onclick event and having no success.  The goal of this is to provide basic password protection for a link on a webpage.  This is intended to keep out the average internet surfer who doesn't have the password.

Currently, the onmouseover and onmouseout events work properly but nothing happens onclick.

Here is my code (please tell me what I am missing):

```
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>
        function passWord() {
            var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password', ' ');
            if (pass1.toLowerCase() = "letmein") {
                alert('Correct');
                window.open('students.html');
                return;
            } else {
                alert('Password Incorrect; Access Denied');
                return;
            }
        }
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<img name="image1" src="Button_1_-_Financial_Mouseout_B_W.jpg" border="0" HEIGHT="31" WIDTH="308" onclick "passWord()" onmouseover="image1.src='Button_1_-_Financial_Mouseover_B_W.jpg';" onmouseout="image1.src='Button_1_-_Financial_Mouseout_B_W.jpg';">

</BODY>
```

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: You will need to change if (pass1.toLowerCase() = "letmein") { to if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") {. Note the double equal sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to put equation symbol there:

```
onclick "passWord()"
```

the correct attribute declaration is:

```
onclick="passWord()"
```

Also I recommend to close all the open HTML tags. You have not closed img tag.
**Full working code:**

```
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>
        function passWord() {
            var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password', ' ');
            if (pass1.toLowerCase() = "letmein") {
                alert('Correct');
                window.open('students.html');
                return;
            } else {
                alert('Password Incorrect; Access Denied');
                return;
            }
        }
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<img name="image1" src="Button_1_-_Financial_Mouseout_B_W.jpg" border="0" HEIGHT="31" WIDTH="308" onclick="passWord()" onmouseover="image1.src='Button_1_-_Financial_Mouseover_B_W.jpg';" onmouseout="image1.src='Button_1_-_Financial_Mouseout_B_W.jpg';"/>

</BODY>
```

Comment: ummm you missed the if (pass1.toLowerCase() = "letmein") error (assignment not comparison) :-)